# Kryonet/LibGdx received not called on client using android emulator, but works on device

Tags: libgdx, kryonet

I'm using KryoNet with LibGdx to implement some network logic.

It works fine when running desktop client, and it also works when I test it on some Android devices, but on some others it does not work. It also does not work on an Android Emulator.

What exactly does not work is the received method in the Listener for client. Every other method in the Listener gets called, (connected, disconnected) so I know for sure the connection is up, but not received(Connection c, Object o).

It does work the other way around though, when the client sends a message to the server.

Please help, and if there is some specific code that could help, tell me and I'll gladly post it.

Edit: I was sending using UDP, but I changed it to TCP just to test, and then it worked fine. However, I'm making a game and I'm sending data quite frequently so I'd love to be able to use UDP. Anything I can do to try to understand what the issue is?